# bootstrap popover not removed from DOM immediately after destroy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

calling popover.('destroy') on a bootstrap popover doesn't destroy the element immediately - it remains in the DOM for about 300ms.  i don't see any configurable value in the docs on this, and i am unable to see why this happens in the source.

has anyone encountered this?  it's causing me trouble in integration tests since i don't want to wait 300ms before testing for removal.

Comment: Maybe call jQuery `remove()` ?

Comment: What version of bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

so i've figured it out - the issue was the animation property in the popover options.  by default it's set to true.  on a destroy there's a hide and then removed called, with an animation for hide.  i set animation to false in the popover options and it gets removed immediately.